# Is fromInteger supposed to be a ring homomorphism?

Tags: haskell, algebra

Until today I had the assumption that `fromInteger` in the `Num` class was a ring homomorphism.  I had assumed this because integer is is coterminal so every ring must have a unique homomorphism from integer, so it made sense that `Num`, which is basically the ring class of the standard library, would include that homomorphism.

However today I was reading the laws for `Num` and saw that `fromInteger` is *not* required to be a homomorphism, but only required to preserve identities.  So for example we can implement the Klein 4 group, and have `fromInteger` map `1` to multiplicative identity and everything else to the addative identity, and the result is a legal `Num` instance but not a homomorphism.

```hs
type Klein4
  = ( Bool
    , Bool
    )

instance
  (
  )
    => Num Klein4
  where
  ( a, b ) + ( c, d )
    = ( a /= c
      , b /= d
      )
  ( a, b ) * ( c, d )
    = ( a && b
      , b && d
      )
  negate
    = id
  fromInteger x
    = ( x == 1
      , x == 1
      )
```

This is a little surprising to me. So my question is why is this the case?  Is the intention that `fromInteger` is a ring homomorphism and I'm just being pedantic, or is there a good use case where you might want to define `fromInteger` in a way that it is not a homomorphism (and still follows the `Num` laws)?

Comment: I don't think `Num` was ever expected to be formally equivalent to a ring. It was just meant to cover the basic overloading of `(+)` and `(*)` that your average programmer might expect. See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude for a more concerted effort to model various structures.

Comment: The average programmer probably doesn't know what a ring homomorphism is, but will notice when `a*(b+c) != a*b + a*c`.

Comment: Does `Num` *have* laws? I had always thought it was just the wild west as far as implementations go, but if you have a link to some canonical laws, I'd love to see them

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Technically `Num` does not, except the documentation lists properties it is "expected to have" [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Num).  I think the distinction between laws and expected properties is pretty fine, but maybe I should have been more precise in my wording.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo practically speaking `Num` is, for better or for worse, indeed a pretty Wild-West class. But I agree that it should at least approximate the class of rings.

Comment: Also sadly, `Num` includes `abs` and `signum`, which aren't ring operations. I'd love to see those diked out.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I expect `fromInteger` to be a ring homomorphism and would be very surprised and annoyed to find an instance that didn't have that property.

Of course, `Float` and `Double` have to be the exception to this, as to every good property. Suffice it to say that I am very surprised and annoyed by this:

```
> fromInteger (2^64) + fromInteger (-1) == (fromInteger (2^64-1) :: Double)
False
```

Most of the other proposed `Num` properties are broken by `Float` and `Double`, too.

I don't know of any practical types that satisfy all the current `Num` laws but not `fromInteger x + fromInteger y == fromInteger (x+y)`.